# GuzzleHTTP malformed URL error with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, curl, guzzle, malformed

I am using Laravel 5.1 with GuzzleHTTP 6.1 and I am using the `thenPing()` method on the laravel scheduler to request a web page when the scheduled task is over

Unfortunately I keep getting a CURL malformed error. This only happens when I try to set the $url variable from the closure, and everything works if I set it in the schedule function.

I am unable to understand the reason for the error.

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{$url;

    $schedule->call(function() use(&$url){
    GLOBAL $var;

      DB::table('chk')->where('id',1)->update(['val'=>$var]);
      $var++;
       $url="http://localhost/wallst/laravel/public/pinger/4";

  })->everyMinute()->thenPing($url);
}
```

This is the schedule function. Please help me.